# Programming language for HPC

Tags: python, c++, c, hpc

I'm planning on building a program that will carry out HPC. I'm aware that C/C++ is significantly better than Python in terms of the speed of computation. However, I'm not yet proficient in C/C++, so do you think it'll be wise to build a fully functioning prototype of sorts in Python and then get it rewritten in C/C++ by others/me in the future.

Comment: Short is yes.  Something to think about as well is there are a growing number of examples where Python is used extensively in HPC environments.  My co-authors and I did something along these lines in http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6583 with the caveat that some of the underpinnings were in Fortran.  Also check out https://github.com/mikaem/spectralDNS as another example.

Comment: What is your definition of HPC? 36-core workstation, Linux cluster, custom supercomputer?

Comment: It really all depends on what your skill level is in each language, what you plan on running it on, and what libraries you end up using. I think I used to align more with the PyClaw authors (I nearly worked with some of them), but the more HPC work I do, the more I tend to just write codes in C or C++. Plus, IIRC, Aron mentioned having to fiddle with loading the Python interpreter at scale for large-scale PyClaw runs on Shaheen. For small scale HPC work, I didn't have any trouble getting mpi4py running.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a good idea to stick with Python if you have expertise with that. I am assuming that this means you are using numpy/scipy. Depending on what you exactly want to do, well-written numpy/scipy code can be very fast and even comparable to C performance.

If you really need the extra speed of C, you can use [Cython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) so that you keep the majority of the code in Python and write only the bottleneck in C.

Answer (score 0):

Python can be used for HPC with no problem. Most computation intensive work will be done with libraries written in C/C++ such as Numpy/Scipy. You can write your key algorithm in C/C++ also. Even if you want to write algorithms in python, there are plenty of methods to gain comparable performance to C/C++. Cython compiles program written with python-like syntax to C; Numba compiles your key algorithms (a python function for example) to C when needed.

HPC is not only about performance on a single computer, you have the choice to use cluster or GPUs to further enhance the computation performance. Python is good at that also.